# Real time conflict detection design pattern in Angular inside a form

Tags: sql, angular, validation, templates, design-patterns

I'm using Angular8 with a SQL backend and FormBuilder to validate the local object in real time.

I'm building an interface right now for a project that allows the user to rent equipments for an event.

There is a multi-page form that allows the user to create an "Event" and this "Event" can contains many "Reservations".

For example, a dumb example of an "Event" could look like this :

```
Event: Music festival
Reservation 1 : 2019-12-01 --> 2019-12-04
- 8 tables
- 2 chairs
- 4 brooms
Reservation 2 : 2019-12-01 --> 2019-12-02
- 1 DJ table
Reservation 3 : 2019-12-03 --> 2019-12-04
- 1 Laptop
```

I would like the user to get a real time feedback of the current availabiliy of an equipment before and after adding it to a reservation.

My first instinct was to query the backend for the current availability of X equipment for the Y and Z dates. I would then take this "availability count" and add it in a map.

For example :

```
// Availabilities map
{
  "2019-12-03-2019-12-04": {
    "id_table": 16
  },
}
```

Then in my angular template, I can fetch the availability count in the map, substract to it the total amount of tables in my form and display a warning message if the remaining count is < 0.

The issue is that adding a function call in my template seems really dirty, I can already feel the atrocious amount of calls that will be made anytime the form change or anytime a button is pressed. There must be a better way to handle this situation, because right now I would have in my .html something as ugly as :

```
<td>{{
  this.availabilityService.getAvailabilityFor(equipment.id, this.dateResMin, this.dateResMax)
  - this.formService.getTotalCountFor(equipment.id)
}}</td>
```

Which means at least two service calls everytime the change detection happens and at least one http call anytime getAvailabilityFor() is called for an equipment or a date that isn't yet in the map.

**An alternative way ?**

I'm thinking that for each Reservation, I should fetch the backend to get a list of all the equipments and their respective availability for the current dateMin and dateMax. Then, when adding an equipment to the reservation, I would locally know how many are available right now and would be able to easily display if the quantity is valid or not.

But with this flow, I don't know what to do when the "dateMin" or "dateMax" of the reservation changes.

I can easily query the backend a second time to get the new list of "Equipments with their availabilities", but what can I do to update my current form with the latest information ?

I'm now stuck with a "validated" form that contains the availability count for the previous dates, and a list of equipments with the availabilities for the NEW dates. I can't find a clean way to patch the current form after fetching the new data.

I'm sorry for the long question and it's probably impossible to understand what I'm trying to say, but I'm having a hard time finding a clean flow for this situation, especially knowing that the user can revisit the Event and edit the date and quantity fields. I need to find a way to validate everything when the page load, on each date change while also offering the user a list of equipments to choose from (with their respective availability count that depends on the reservation dateMin and dateMax).

Comment: With .NET backend, you can have a look at SignalR. But from what you have been describing, you seem to go to your database from your Angular which sounds a bad design to me.

Comment: Yeah, basically when the user is adding equipments to his new "event", that isn't created yet, I want to display if a conflict is detected. For example : Oops, there are no tables available for those dates. But I'm having a hard time finding an efficient way to query the backend in a logical way without adding http calls in my template.

Comment: No matter what, you will always need to go to your database to find out whether things are available which involves HTTP calls.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, but it feels so wrong when the calls are coming from functions called in the template. I'll probably need to abstract what is shown in the html and actually fetch the equipment with its availabilities before building the presentation data / adding it to my form. But since my form doesn't need the "availability" data and only cares about the equipmentId, dateMin, dateMax, it's so hard for me not to polute everything in a clean manner.

Comment: Basically you have a background HTTP polling in your component `ts` and updates a variable. You then put that variable into your HTML.